# java.lang.linkageerror.....(instance of org/powermock..)

Tags: java, jdbc, junit4, powermock

While running my JUnit test class, I am getting the following-

```
ERROR Statuslogger Could not reconfigure JMX
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader(instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"****************************************************
WARNING: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.***************
```

Can any one please help me understand what wrong I might have done to get such error.

Some more details-
It's a struts project. I am using ojdbc8. Code has used JdbcTemplate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something conflicts with `javax.management.*`

Please try to  add `@PowerMockIgnore` to your test class:

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class YourTest {

}
```

This annotation tells PowerMock to defer the loading of classes with the names supplied to `javax.management.` to the system classloader.